# How to add KML file to PostgreSQL as polygon in nodejs

Tags: postgresql, kml, node-js

I have a nodejs server which is connected to PostgreSQL database. I need to create a polygon by using coordinates JSON with fields. In the PostgreSQL database there is a default column as "geom". I tried to add in this column but I think syntax is different with JSON geometry. How can I create a polygon by this way?

```json
coordinates: "34.26874524537533,35.56726640638707,0 34.26879192651798,35.56702498591847,0 34.26950518727496,35.56715326545641,0 34.26951725656846,35.56706234584355,0 34.27010825157995,35.56717295252424,0 34.26990692317912,35.56756882284464,0 34.26974649403571,35.56795560177618,0 34.26906223739066,35.56777705096091,0 34.26860721018177,35.56769205885733,0 34.26874524537533,35.56726640638707,0"
```

```js
  const deedID = deed.id;
  const coordinate = deed.kml.coordinate; //coming from kml file by using xml parser
  pool.query(
    `INSERT INTO mymap ("geom","deedID") VALUES (${coordinate},${deedID})`,
    (err, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(err);
      pool.end();
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ST_PolygonFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PolygonFromText.html). You need to modify your coordinates string beforehand. If you have z values you need to keep the third value (always 0 in your case), if not you need to pop those values.

```js
// Keep the 0 values
coordinate = coordinate.split(" ").map(x => x.split(",").join(" ")).join(", ");

// Without the 0 values
coordinate = coordinate.split(" ").map(x => {
   const t = x.split(","); 
   t.splice(-1); 
   t.join(" "); 
   return t
}).join(", ")

const sqlInsert = `INSERT INTO mymap ("geom","deedID") VALUES (ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON((${coordinate}))'),${deedID})`
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answer. Its worked but when added geometry by this way, in map there is a only a point not a polygon. How can i fix this ?

Comment: What type is your "geom" column?

Comment: type is geomety

Comment: also its going to zero point of world  https://prnt.sc/BToNgX7E0sMY

Comment: I guess you are using WGS84 / EPSG:4326 as CRS - so the type should be  geography(Polygon,4326)

Comment: Have a read here: https://tinyurl.com/yckkks9w

Comment: its worked problem is solved. thank you so much^^ i changed type to geography